# How to do a proper migration once and for all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, migrate

I have a few migrations for my users table and it has become a mess that I don't really follow myself :)

Ideally, what I want to do is use the Devise library for auth, and create my users table through that.

Should I do a drop table users, and merge my accumulated migrate files into one, and then run rake db:migrate ? Or is there a better way to do it? What is the good practice way of doing this?

Also, I'd like to add 3 more columns to the new migration for fistName,lastName,company fields to the users table.  Where should I add that so those fields get created?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: migrations correcting the preceding are natural part of the workflow, don't fight against that: there is no real added value.

Comment: @apneadiving Yeah but my concern is that this is still my dev environment and I can change it freely. Once I put it on stage and further, I want the migrations to be nice and elegant. So I want to get them right from as few tries as possible.

Comment: in this case, make everything clean in one migration file, delete the  db and migrate

Comment: @apneadiving Should I just re-run the old migrations after dropping the database? Will they all run despite having a time stamp that has already been migrated? I kind of don't understand how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're in dev, and alone, you can change your migration files the way you want (I'm still not convinced it's that useful, see my comment above).

Well, once you've edited everything as you want:

- delete your current database: `rake db:drop`
- recreate it: `rake db:create`
- migrate: `rake db:migrate`

The process of migrations is traced in the database itself:

one table is created and named `schema_migrations`, each entry is an already made migration with the timestamp as an id.

Because you dump the db, there is no more trace and you can remigrate.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you can do these 3 steps just with `rake db:reset`